# One Node to Gather Them All

Tags: neo4j

Say I am managing collectibles. I have thousands of baseball trading cards, thousands still of gaming cards (think Magic: the Gathering), and then thousands and thousands of doilies.

The part of me that's been steeped in relational databases for 20+ years is uncomfortable with the idea of thousands of Neo4J nodes floating out in space.

So I am inclined to gather them all with a node such as (:BASEBALL_CARDS), (:MTG_CARDS), and of course (:DOILIES). The idea is that these are singletons.

Now if I want all baseball cards that perhaps refer to a certain player, I could do something like:

```
(:BASEBALL_CARDS)-[GATHERS]->(:BASEBALL_CARD)-[:FEATURES]->(p:PLAYER {name: '...'})
```

It's very comforting to have the :BASEBALL_CARDS singleton, but does it do anything more than could be accomplished by indexing :BASEBALL_CARD?

```
(:BASEBALL_CARD)-[:FEATURES]->(p:PLAYER {name: '...'})
```

Is it best-practice to have thousands of free-ranging nodes?

Answer (score 2):

One exceptional strong point of the graph database is the local query: the relationship lives in the instance, not in the type. A particular challenge (apart from modelling well) is determining the starting point of the local query (and keeping it local, i.e., avoiding path explosions). In Neo4j 1.x your One Node was a way to achieve a starting point for a certain kind of query. With 2.x and the introduction of labels, indexing `:BaseballCard` is the standard way to accomplish the same. If the purpose of that One Node is as a starting point for the kind of query in your example, then you are better off using a label index. A common problem in 1.x was that a node with an increasing number of relationships of the same type and direction eventually becomes a bottle neck for traversals. People started partitioning your One Node into A Paged Handful of Nodes, something like

```
(:BaseballCards)-[:GATHERS]->(:BaseballCards1to10000)-[:GATHERS]->(:BaseballCard)
```

The purpose of finding a starting point for the local query is often better served by labels, perhaps in combination with a basic, ordinary, local traversal, than by A Handful of Nodes. Then again, if it calms your nerves or satisfies your sense of the epic to have such a node, by all means have it. Because of the locality of queries, it will do you no harm.

In your example, however, neither the One Node nor an index on `:BaseballCard` would best serve as the starting point of the local query. The most particular pattern of interest is instead the name of the player. If you index `(:Player)` on `name` you will get the best starting point. The traversal across the one or handful* of `[:FEATURES]` relationships is very cheap and with a simple test on the other end for the `:BaseballCard` label, you are done. You could of course maintain the One Node for all players that share a name...

In my most humble opinion there is little need for discomfort. I do, however, want to affirm and commend your unease, in this one regard: that the graph is most powerful for connected data. The particular connection gathering the baseball cards doesn't seem to add new understanding or improve performance, but wherever there is disconnected data there is the potential for discovering exciting and meaningful patterns. Perhaps in the future the cards will be connected through patterns that signify their range of value, or the quality of their lamination, or a linked list of previous owners, or how well they work as conversations starters on a date. The absence of relationships is a call to find that One Missing Link that brings tremendous insight and value into your data.

* Handful, assuming that more than one baseball card features the same player, or some baseball players are also featured on cards of Magic: The Gathering. I'm illiterate in both domains, so I want to at least allow for the possibility.

Answer (score 2):

It is ironic that you are concerned about nodes "floating out in space", when the whole idea behind graph DBs is making the *connections* between nodes a first class DB construct.

But I think your actual concern is that nodes do not "belong to a table" (in relational DB parlance). So, you would feel more comfortable in creating a special singleton node that in some sense takes the place of a table, from which you can access all the nodes that ought belong to that table.

A node `label` can be seen as the equivalent of a "table name". So, not only is there no need for you to also create a singleton "table node", doing so would be wasteful in DB resources, and complicate and slow down your queries. And neo4j can quickly access all the nodes with the same label.

Comment: Hey it isn't like I have training or anything :-D